# how do I break up a regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-closure

```
  String.prototype.is_email = function() {
      return this.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)\b/);
  };
```

I'm trying to get all my javascript files to lint under closure linter ( http://code.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto.html ); how do I break up a Regular Expression using the /regex/ syntax.

Line 24, E:0110: Line too long (200 characters).
Found 1 errors, including 0 new errors, in 1 files (0 files OK).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`RegExp(pattern, modifiers)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and pass the pattern as a string. The string can be built up in small parts using concatenation.

Comment: And this have the advantage of putting comments on each part of the regexp, which is kinda complex. Nice answer.

Comment: Warning: if you do this you'll need to remember to put an extra backslash before each backslash in your regexp.

Answer (score 2):

Very hackish: add a newline in the regexp (to break the long line into smaller ones), escape that newline by prepending a `\` and place a `{0}` directly after it to prevent it from being taken into account, ever...

```
var regex = /abc\
{0}def/;

regex.test("abcdef")   // true
regex.text("abc\ndef") // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple function for combining regular expressions to make debugging them a little more manageable.

```js
  var joinRegExp = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return new RegExp(args.reduce(function(str, exp) {
      return str + exp.toString().replace(/\//g, '');
    }, ''));
  };
```

So you could break your expression into something like this.

```
var local = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+/;
var localOpt = /(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*/;
var domain = /(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+/;
var tld = /(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)\b/;
```

And then join them.

```
var emailPattern = joinRegExp(local, localOpt, /@/, domain, tld);
```

You can check out this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/I9PRt2vo3wGvqYiHsrGZ) for a demo.